# Clock and date javascript

Tags: javascript

Im creating a JS clock/date. I previously got the time to work perfectly then I decided to add more onto my clock (date). Right now I cant figure why it isn't working. If anyone could give me tip or idea how to fix it, I would greatly appreciate it.

```
function timedate()
    {
    var currentTime = new Date();
    var hours = currentTime.getHours();
    var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
    var dn="PM"
    var d = currentTime.getDate(); <--
    var day = (d < 10) ? '0' + d : d;
    var m = currentTime.getMonth() + 1; <--
    var month = (m < 10) ? '0' + m : m;
    var yy = currentTime.getYear(); <--
    var year = (yy < 1000) ? yy + 1900 : yy;
    if (hours<12)
 {
    dn="AM"
 }
    if (hours>12)
 {
    hours=hours-12
 }
    if (hours==0)
 {
    hours=12
 }
    if (minutes<=9)
 {
    minutes="0"+minutes 
 }
 var clocklocation = document.getElementById('timedate');
 clocklocation.innerHTML = "" +hours+":"+minutes+dn+""+day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
 setTimeout("timedate()", 1000); 
    }
timedate();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it isn't working"? Is it throwing an error?

Comment: I hope these bits `<--` aren't literally in your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works, it is just not visible because you do not have seconds showing

Also change

```
setTimeout("timedate()", 1000);
```

to

```
setTimeout(timedate, 1000);
```

because it is not recommended

**and remove the <--**

Make sure it runs onload or after the tag you want to show it in

Alternatively remove the line and change

```
timedate();
```

to

```
setInterval(timedate,1000)
```

```js
const pad = num => ("0" + num).slice(-2);
const timedate = () => {
  const currentTime = new Date();
  let hours = currentTime.getHours();
  const minutes = pad(currentTime.getMinutes());
  const seconds = pad(currentTime.getSeconds());

  const d = currentTime.getDate();
  const day = pad(d);
  const month = pad(currentTime.getMonth() + 1);
  const yy = currentTime.getFullYear();

  let dn = "PM"
  if (hours <= 12) dn = "AM";
  if (hours >= 12) hours -= 12;
  if (hours == 0) hours = 12;
  hours = pad(hours);
  document.getElementById('timedate').innerHTML = "" +
    hours + ":" +
    minutes + ":" +
    seconds + dn + " " +
    day + "/" + month + "/" + yy;
}
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  setInterval(timedate, 1000);
});
```

```html
<span id="timedate"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set the timeout with `setTimeout(timedate, 1000)` instead of your current magic string version, [it works](http://jsfiddle.net/DBMsC/2/)<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> I took the liberty of adding seconds to your code as well, to make it obvious that the clock updates. Of course, you also need to remove `<--` from your code.</sup>

Comment: So did I :) but I did it first

Comment: Yeah - by not enough for me to see your post before I wrote mine ;)

Comment: Actually the magic string version does work, not recommended but works