# JavaScript Time picker insert from real time

Tags: javascript, php, html, task-parallel-library

In a row I have a clock, which shows the time when I log in. How I can make it real, so its ticking all the time and shows real time? Please see picture ( row with 20.03.21 22:25 )

cms with time

[image]

```html
<input type="text" class="light1" name="Date" value="[[:Date:]]" /><br/>
<input type="text" class="light1" id="txt" name="Now" readonly="readonly" value="[:NOW:]" />
<span style="position:relative; top:0px; left:0px;"><a href="javascript:;" onclick="$('#AddDataForm input[name=Date]').val($('#AddDataForm input[name=Now]').val());" style="text-decoration:none; position:absolute; right:3px; top:-2px;">&uarr;</a></span>
```

Comment: Where is the code for the date? Also why not search for javascript clock?

Comment: I will try to find the code. There is small arrow, when I press it the time is added to another row. Clock is changing when I change something on site, but I would like that row is showing all the time real clock, not that clock when I change something. Thanks, will try to find data for clock

Comment: See the dupe I posted

Comment: $Data = array(); $now = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            if(strtotime($row['Min'])<$now) $row['Alert'] = '#F00; font-weight:700;';
            $Data[] = $row;
        }

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/Y58pM/ - if you want the clock to run from your server time, then change `const currentTime = new Date();` to `const currentTime = new Date('<?= $now ?>');`

Comment: I think this is code for javascript on site

Comment: I cannot read unformatted code in a comment. PLEASE update the QUESTION

Comment: sorry, just cannot get it working :(

Comment: Use `'[[:Date:]]'` instead of `'<?= $now ?>'` in my example

Comment: ok, but I cannot still get code working, How to add ```<span id="timedate"></span>``` to ```<input type="text" class="light1" name="Now" readonly="readonly"  value="[:NOW:]" />  
                    <span style="position:relative; top:0px; left:0px;">``` if I remove old clock I cannot insert it into another row. Javascript code for data input is ```<a href="javascript:;" onclick="$('#AddDataForm input[name=Date]').val($('#AddDataForm input[name=Now]').val());" style="text-decoration:none; position:absolute; right:3px; top:-2px;">&uarr;</a>```

Comment: give the field an ID of timedate and change innerHTML to value. Please do some work yourself

Comment: sorry, I am trying to do it, but my knowledge is not so great, Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code taken from [Clock and date javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15993018/clock-and-date-javascript)

```js
const pad = num => ("0" + num).slice(-2);
const timedate = () => {
  const currentTime = new Date(new Date().getTime() + diff);
  let hours = currentTime.getHours();
  const minutes = pad(currentTime.getMinutes());
  const seconds = pad(currentTime.getSeconds());

  const d = currentTime.getDate();
  const day = pad(d);
  const month = pad(currentTime.getMonth() + 1);
  const yyyy = currentTime.getFullYear();

/*  let dn = "PM"
  if (hours <= 12) dn = "AM";
  if (hours >= 12) hours -= 12;
  if (hours == 0) hours = 12; */
  hours = pad(hours);
  timeOutput.value = "" +
    yyyy + "/" + month + "/" + day +
    " " +
    hours + ":" +
    minutes + ":" +
    seconds// + dn;
}
let timeOutput;
let serverTime;
let diff;
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  timeOutput = document.getElementById("timedate");
  serverTime = new Date("2020/03/21 22:23:24");// change to new Date("[[:Date:]]"); for example
  diff = new Date().getTime() - serverTime.getTime();
  setInterval(timedate, 1000);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="timedate" class="light1" name="Date" value="" /><br/>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a text input to update every second with the time, you could implement something like this:

```
<input type="text" id="myTime" />

<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        setInterval(function () {
            var newDate = new Date();

            document.getElementById('myTime').value = newDate.toLocaleString();
        }, 1000);
    }
</script>
```